# The smooth condition of Sard's theorem

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, differential-topology

As I have learnt in my lecture, the proof to Sard's theorem at the last step has shown if $k>\frac{n}{m}-1$ the $f(C_k)$ has zero measure in $M$. But the statement of Sard's theorem said $k\geqslant n-m+1$. 
$C_k$ represents the set of all derivatives till $k$-th order are vanishing.

How does it come?

Comment: What is $C_k$? Please explain your notation.

Comment: this proof: http://web.stanford.edu/~amwright/Sard.pdf